# check with a regular expression of the domains of the email addresses

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to filter domain names on emails
because I want to accept what emails from whoever's coming from gmail and hotmail.

that's what I did, but it still turns me around, false.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+(@gmail|@hotmail)\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i;
```

Thanks

Comment: `)\\.[` should be `)\.[`

Comment: ^ is correct, which becomes clear when using a visualization tool, like https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%2B%5C.%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%2B(%40gmail%7C%40hotmail)%5C%5C.%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B2%2C4%7D%24%2Fi

Comment: I'll also add that this regex is questionable (as a general rule) as it excludes `.`, `_`, `-`, `+` and a bunch of other characters that are _valid_ in the username portion. If all you want is the domain, just look for that and ignore (accept all: `*`) what comes before the `@` symbol.

Comment: @msanford This looks like it may be trying to parse institutional emails: `bill.gates@gmail.com`, for example. I'm unsure though

Comment: @JamesMonger That's quite possible... I'll make my comment more generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct regex to use is this:

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+(@gmail|@hotmail)\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i`

The change is to replace `\\` (after `@hotmail)`) with `\`. Having `\\` escapes the `\` character so it expects it in your value, whereas you want to use the `\` in conjunction with the `.` in order to expect a `.` character.

You can use tools like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) to see how the changes you make to your expression affect the way it parses strings.